# What would be a safe way to block these SPAM e-mails?

Tags: email, spam-prevention

In the last month, I've been getting numerous e-mails which all follow a clear pattern (well, it's clear to a human eye, at least). They are sent from e-mail addresses such as:

```
amzn.2.gmsu.70155@s6x6dkgto4db1a.w20c2-9332.neakular.cf
ehar.2.gmsu.70076@avf6fvhptq4gvs.w0.tytqzjfx.ml
cvsp.2.gmsu.70139@5z6ad3ma5u43dr.w985-1.bxfi7rp.ml
adtp.7.gmsu.70098@986dgm9ef43erj.w1963-4532.hcix7xbl.ml
adtp.6.gmsu.69993@ws6f6h1tg4nndg.w28dd-1.rssiqxgo.ml
amzn.2.gmsu.69999@lb6ebelqh64fnv.w2114-1.mvgkksfi.ga
zpln.2.gmsu.69967@4q96a5bs83j4lm.w302c-1.hl3yhyb.cf
cvsp.2.gmsu.69995@5z6aahvehu3u3r.w28b2-1.ro2jmorp.ga
cvsp.2.gmsu.69965@ym36ejhqe4kohc.w61-1.qsnzuyc.ml
adtp.6.gmsu.69962@4v96ddqflq41qq.w0.cvao2fty.ga
amzn.2.gmsu.69963@zp64fd4bb4lkmf.w6b9-1.vpligvsy.cf
adtp.6.gmsu.69927@vl6em02kf4kgd3.w0.wegonwel.ml
zpln.2.gmsu.69934@7q6fbcrkn4m3l7.wc35-47e9.mhvukwcc.ga
lask.2.gmsu.69924@c56ghboal4t0f0.w0.xrzfuus.gq
cvsp.2.gmsu.69926@8z6d5cd7du43b6.w15a1-1.cdehisvh.ml
```

Seems to me that no legitimate site would use such "weird" adresses/hostnames. I first thought of just blackholing any incoming e-mail from "*.gmsu.*", but I'm worried (as always) that it might be too greedy.

The subjects are like this:

```
 Welcome to A Free $50 Amazon.com® Courtesy Shopping Card (LAS…
Browse matches at no cost on eharmony
❤️Welcome to a Complimentary $50 CVS/pharmacy® gift card (Your …
$100 Visa Gift Card from Protect your Home if you choose ADT Mo…
ADT Monitored System can help protect your home, plus a $100 gi…
 Welcome to A FREE $50 Amazon.com® Gift Card (LAST NOTICE: Onl…
Need Funds? Get up to $15,000 FAST!
❤️Welcome to Your Own $50 CVS/pharmacy® gift card (Your email c…
❤️Welcome to Your Own $50 CVS/pharmacy® gift card (Your email c…
ADT Monitored System can help protect your home, plus a $100 gi…
 Welcome to A Complimentary $50 Amazon.com® Charge Card (NOTIC…
ADT Monitored System can help protect your home, plus a $100 gi…
Get Approved for a Loan up to $15,000!
20% off LASIK Special - Schedule your free evaluation now
❤️Welcome to Your Own $50 CVS/pharmacy® gift card (Your frequen…
```

Why don't automated filters prevent these "obvious" garbage letters from ever reaching my e-mail account in the first place?

I have a good mind to outright block any of those countries such as .ml, .ga, .cf, etc. But again, that would really suck if somebody from there at some point has a legitimate reason to e-mail me. However, the fact remains that I have not once in my life ever received a non-SPAM e-mail message from any of those countries above.

Comment: And I have to say that this is a tech support site and not a place for rants. Those paragraphs would be more useful if they talked about whether you run your own mail server or use a hosted service, and which SMTP and/or antispam software you are using. Does your blocking feature accept regexes?

Comment: "I'm shocked by just how badly e-mails can be messed up" - overall your post seems to be more focused on complaining than actually looking for a solution. Essential information is missing, e.g. which service / provider do you use? Which mail client? Have you tried any spam filters?...

Answer (score 1):

All of these addresses match the regex:

```
^[a-z]{4}\.[0-9]\.gmsu\.[0-9]{5,6}@[a-z0-9]{14}\.w[0-9a-f].*\.(cf|ga|gq|ml)$
```

Even if it were from the same TLD as the spam messages, it would be very unlikely for some completely unrelated sender to accidentally use exactly the same overall address format.